# i am doing webscraping so this error is occuring kindly check this out?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-21-b281566ea133> in <module>
----> 1 desc = soup.findall("td",{"class":"views-field views-field-search-api-excerpt views-field-field-api-description hidden-xs visible-md visible-sm col-md-8"})

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26603435/beautifulsoup-typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-callable)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're using beautifulsoup version 3 & it has stopped receiving updates in 2012; it is severely out of date now. I strongly urge you to upgrade:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

and

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

The `Element.find_all()` method is available in latest major version. Use it instead of `Element.findall()` and try again.